# Run a script – with spaces in its path, a parameter, and a variable for the parameter value – with the script module?

Tags: ansible

My task in my playbook:

```
- name: Run a script
  script: '"./files/name of a script.ps1" -Param1 {{ variable_name }}'
```

The above is only the latest attempting at quoting/escaping I've tried. Regardless, I get an error like this when I run the playbook containing the above task:

```
TASK [Run a script] *****************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbook.yml:38
<192.168.200.245> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: SOME-HOST\Administrator on PORT 5986 TO 192.168.200.245
<192.168.200.245> EXEC Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
(New-Item -Type Directory -Path $env:temp -Name "ansible-tmp-1466538051.8-95578181041077").FullName | Write-Host -Separator '';
<192.168.200.245> PUT "/etc/ansible/"./files/name\" TO "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1466537998.0-243829631467080\name"
fatal: [some-host]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "file or module does not exist: \"/etc/ansible/\"./files/name\\\""}
```

This also doesn't work, and fails with the same error as above:

```
  script: ./files/name\ of\ a\ script.ps1 -Param1 {{ variable_name }}
```

I'm running Ansible version 2.1.0.0 (according to `ansible --version` on my control machine).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is either a 'bug'](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/m57TG6XssOM/15wYu-CFKAAJ):

> Please file a bug on this under [the ansible/ansible project](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) – it looks like it's not a Windows-specific issue, given where it's failing. No guarantees we'll be able to thread the needle correctly for separating the script name from the args in the `free_form` script arg, but others have asked for a more explicit separation between script name and args in our script action, and this would be an excellent case for it.

[or a 'missing feature'](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16414).